# TotalCommander's Lister Window won't show up in foreground in Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, total-commander

From my Windows 10, I am connecting via Remote Desktop Connection to another Windows 10 PC. Here I am opening a text file by pressing F3 in Total Commander. The lister window appears on the bottom taskbar, but the window won't show up in the foreground, even if I explicitly click it in the taskbar!! Everything works fine when I am doing this directly on the computer. The problem is only present when connecting via Remote Desktop Connection. Is Remote Desktop somehow changing the behaviour of Windows? It shouldn't, probably!

TC is version <strike>9.22a</strike> 9.51.

PS: not sure if it matters, but the native resolution of my client (local PC) is 3000x2000, the native resolution of the server I think is like 1920x1280 or the like, but in the remote desktop it works in the high dpi 3000x2000.

Comment: Works fine here - just tried it using Remote Desktop connection to the other Windows 10 machine. Both Windows 10 machines 20H2 and Total Commander V9.51 64-bit.

Comment: @John thanks. You inspired me to upgrade TC to 9.51, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I look around to see if I can find a reason for this. I am not sure what it could be.

Comment: It could be the resolution issue. Both my machines are 1920x1280.  Try to use the 1920x1080 resolution on the high res machine by adjust settings in RDP.

Comment: @John I tried and the problem disappeared!! Wow! But the RD is creepy small now, cannot read it... even with different resolutions and 200% zoom.... this solution works but it's effectively unworkable on my already small laptop screen... Perhaps there could be some way to persuade it to work at my native 3000x2000... without restarting the remote which I am afraid of.

Comment: Try the Windows 10 initial repair steps on both computers. (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.